# how to give the src to image tag in jquery success function in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

This is my success function of jQuery everything is fine but I don't know how to give the URL to the image tag I am doing it like this but it is not showing image

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.data.length > 0) {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            html +=
                `<div class="col-md-4 content_box">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url('all_images/model_logos/ ` +
                data.data[i].model_image +
                `')}}" >
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text"><b>MAKE:</b>` +
                data.data[i].make_id +
                `</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><b>Model:</b>` +
                data.data[i].model +
                `</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><b>model ar:</b>` +
                data.data[i].model_ar +
                `</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to give url there?

Comment: When this function runs and renders HTML, what does that rendered HTML code look like?  You should be able to see it using F12 Developer Tools and then inspect the HTML on your page.  Could you please edit your question and add in the rendered HTML code segment?

Comment: It looks like you're using server-side code on client-side generated html.  `src="{{url(...`.  This won't be parsed as it's not server-side.

Comment: @freedomn-m  Then tell me the correct way to give the src here because other fields are working?

Comment: @devlincarnate it looks fine but not showing image and throwing error like image not found because i know i am using wrong syntax for image and also I don't know the correct way

Comment: `<div class="col-md-4 content_box">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url('all_images/model_logos/ ` +
                            data.data[i].model_image +
                            `')}}" >/////got the problem here

Comment: Well, it _kinda_ can work, but correct syntax would be `<img src="{{ url('all_images/model_logos') }}/${data.data[i].model_image}"/>`. You can't use `data.data[i].model_image` inside of that `url()` function, as that is a PHP/Laravel (back-end) function, while `data` is a JS variable. You need to append it afterwards.

Comment: It didn't work☹️

Comment: Are you sure this is a PHP problem?

Comment: We've shown you the syntax (multiple different ways), you now need to debug it a bit. What is the outputted HTML? Is the `src` attribute on these `<img>` tags ok? When you say "it didn't work", we can't help you further; that statement is meaningless without more context and explanation.

Comment: It is not showing image saying not found

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that? Did you even check the generated markup for errors?

Comment: i am trying to correct the syntax of src because it is giving this error"to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Well, that is a different issue completely. That means the `src` attribute is being generated just fine, but doesn't point at an available image's URL. What is the `src` value? Does it map to a URL for an image?

Comment: @TimLewis exactly it is not getting the correct url to specific image

Comment: For the 4th time, what is the value of the `src`? Were are you images stored? A 404 means a lot more than just the `src` not being generated from the JS correctly. It could be pointing to a URL that is not valid for your image, but until you show that, we can't (and won't) help further.

Comment: I stored images in public/all_images/model_logos and the name of field in database is model_image as public folder is not necessary to define i am defining the src like there is a all_images folder and inside it there is model_image which contains images

Comment: In Laravel, you don't store images in `public` directly... You store them in `storage/app/public/images` (or similar), then you run `php artisan storage:link`, then you use the `asset()` helper, not the `url()` helper: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/show-images-from-storage-folder. For the last time, show me the generated `src` of one of theme `<img>` elements, you're making it _very_ difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @TimLewis i am very sorry for that but i am not getting what you are asking but still this is how i am generating         src <img class="card-img-top" src=" url('all_images/model_logos/) ` +
                            data.data[i].model_image +
                            `
                        " > and this same url is working in my blade file but the url is not getting recognised in my js file ajax's succes function

Comment: @TimLewis can i show you a controller , blade or routes?? the data is coming from a controller

Comment: In your browser, right click > view element, and show me the `src` that is not working. I don't want to see the code, I want to see the actual URL that is being generated!

Comment: @TimLewis     http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/url('all_images/model_logos/)%20model_image_907336_024244_18122022_1682504270.png

Comment: Lol, so yeah, it's still busted, but in a completely different way now... Is this a `.js` file, or a `<script>` inside a `.blade.php` file? If this is a `.js` file, then you can't use `{{ }}` or `url()`, as those are `.blade.php` functions.

Comment: @TimLewis then what should i use?

Comment: Hard-code the URL, or find a way to make `http://127.0.0.1/admin/all_images/model_logos` available as a JS variable. Read through all the comments on your question and the answers, there's tons of information and things for you to try. You can do whatever you need to do to get this to work, but you can't use `{{ }}` or `url()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the closing braces before adding `data.data[i].model_image` to the src:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ url('all_images/model_logos/') }}` + data.data[i].model_image + `" >
```

Comment: You missed the closing `'` after `model_logos/`. Also, all of this is inside `\`` (string interpolation), so there is no need to do `\` + data.data[i].model_image + \``, just do `${data.data[i].model_image}`

Comment: @TimLewis thanks `'` fixed, i've seen the using of string interpolation, however I didn't want to mess with the initial code too much

Comment: All good; there's another answer that shows that too 

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Laravel's blade template syntax ({{ url('all_images/model_logos/') }}) within a JavaScript string. <strike>Since this syntax is processed on the server-side by Laravel, it won't work within your JavaScript code.</strike>

Like the answer above me said, you should place the data.data[i].model_image outside of the url function. Changed my answer accordingly.

Can you try to concat the URL string like this:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ url('all_images/model_logos') }}/${data.data[i].model_image}">
```

It should process the correct image source as the src attribute.

Comment: *"Since this syntax is processed on the server-side by Laravel, it won't work within your JavaScript code."* - That is incorrect. `{{ url() }}` can work within a `<script>` element within a `.blade.php` Template, with the result being a plain string in JS. The issue is trying to use `data.data[i].model_image` **inside** of the `url()` method, as trying to use a JS variable in a PHP function doesn't work; the function has run _long_ before the JS variable is available.

Comment: @freedomn-m Again, not if this is within a `<script>` of a `.blade.php`. `url('all_images/model_logos/')` produces a string, like `http://localhost:8000/all_images/model_logos/`, which you can then append the JS variable to, resulting in a final string of `http://localhost:8000/all_images/model_logos/whatever`. If you try to use the `data` variable inside of `url()`, _then_ you have the issue.

Comment: Strangely, just by adding "again" I realised what you're saying.  The `{{` would/could be parsed when the script is provided (if it's in a .php and not .js), *before* it's sent to the browser.   *If* it was well-formed at that time.

Comment: @TimLewis still getting the same issue

Comment: @freedomn-m You got it! There are definitely better ways to handle this, like a `data` attribute on the HTML associated, or converting `const rootUrl = '{{ url('/') }}';` to a JS variable, then simply doing `src="${rootUrl + data.data[i].model_image}"`, or similar.

Comment: @TimLewis Ah my bad, you're right. The problem was the model_image being in the url function.

Comment: Once again, _almost_ there  Your answer is basically what my comment was trying to say: `<img src="{{ url('all_images/model_logos') }}/${data.data[i].model_image}"/>` (just need to use `${}` for interpolation within `\``)

Comment: Haha I'm stupid. But then the + isn't really necessary right? The {{ }} will be rendered and it will read the whole url.

Comment: You're not stupid, this is just a weird case of working with code that is completely wrapped in `\``, so the entire thing is being interpolated. You'd need the `${}` to tell JS you want to use a variable there. Your current answer is output the `data.data[i].model_image` literally, `src="http://localhost:8000/all_images/model_logos/data.data[i].model_image"`, which for obvious reasons isn't right 

Comment: @freedomn-m See the most recent comment on the question; this is likely a `.js` file... We all assumed otherwise... The asker just needs to not use `{{ }}` and `url()`, as this is not a `.blade.php` file. But this answer (and the other) are still good.

Comment: It is indeed a weird case. I'm learning here. Thanks.